# Android ADB Device Will Not Stay Connected

Tags: android, linux, adb

Recently all my devices have lost connection to adb ... kind of. I've searched all over but can't find this exact issue, so here goes.

The output of 'adb devices' is an empty list, about 95% of the time. If I'm spamming 'adb devices' I'll see an occasional:

```
List of devices attached 
<deviceId>        device
```

but it disappears less than a second afterwards. This happens with my Nexus 7, Nexus 5, and a non-Nexus Asus tablet. The symptoms are identical for all my devices and various USB cables.

Here's what I've tried, unsuccessfully:

1. adb kill-server, adb start-server
2. Other USB cables
3. Other USB ports (front, back, USB 2.0, USB 3.0)
4. Ensure udev rules are correct, restart udev
5. Other devices
6. reinstall kubuntu, reverting to 12.04 (from 14.04)
7. reset Android device to factory

The last steps were out of desperation. And here we are, #8: ask SO for help.

This all worked fine as of 2 days ago, before my upgrade to kubuntu 14.04, which is why I tried #6, assuming it would resolve my issue. It didn't. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unplug and replug the USB cable to the device works for me. Also, I have changed device's settings to never sleep when connected to cable. (but I am on windows 7)

Comment: Thanks, but see step 3, and the device is awake with screen on. Like I said, it does connect briefly, but then disconnects within one second. It does this sporadically. Very confusing and frustrating.

Comment: The adb issues aren't reproducible on other computers. That narrows it down to hardware, firmware, or software issues on the offending computer. Not much help, but there it is

Comment: Installed identical OS on a different computer, and can't reproduce it there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using the adb packaged with android-tools-adb. Why that works while the stock adb in platform-tools did not, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my Windows 8.1 PC. I don't know much about Linux, but I can tell you what I did to solve my problem.

1. Make sure that the Android device is connected as a media device. The notifications bar while the device is connected lets you change this setting.
2. Make sure the device's USB debugging option is checked. This is also can be accessed through the notifications bar.

Sorry if these first two sound a little obvious, but you have to check. Here's what really solved the problem:

1. Check that your computer has the device drivers are installed through the computer's control panel. If you are missing a driver, go to the brand/company website, and they should have a link to download the necessary driver.
2. Make sure that you can see the devices inner files through the computer. If not, then you have a problem that is not related to the adb. Check your computers settings, etc.

I suggest that you really make sure that the problem isn't in the computer. Since the problem began right after your computer's upgrade, it seems like something that happened along the upgrade. If everything is behaving normally on your computer, but only the adb is acting weird, try to re-install the adb and not your computer's system.

BTW, I really recommend that next time, "ask SO for help" would be way higher in your list, at around 2, instead of making unnecessary purchases that eventually did not help you at all

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does help 99% of the other SO questions I've read. However, yes debugging is enabled, yes I can browse files, Linux uses udev and kernel USB drivers instead of OEM custom drivers. It could be USB hardware failure on the computer, but it's strange that everything else works normally (keyboard/mouse/other external media). Fortunately my only purchase in all of this is my time ... so far! :(

Comment: Did you try re-installing the adb? That might do the trick. It takes a while, but it's always worth it if it works.

Comment: Yes, although I did neglect to mention that in the original post. I reinstalled adb somewhere around step 5, and then reinstalled it yet again after the OS reinstall.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall all aspects, like the Java flavors, etc? Anything could have gotten bugged when you upgraded the OS.

Comment: I got a fresh JDK7 from Oracle after I did the OS reinstall. Everything should be clean and latest, and I'm up to date with my kernel patches.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. I really hope you find a solution soon. I would keep looking until I can install apps on my device again.

Comment: @royn1 adb has no dependence on java or the jdk.